# Launchd/Launchctl - pre and post scripting

Tags: macos, launchd, zsh

Is there any way with ld/lctrl to execute pre/post commands similar to systemd's `ExecStartPre`/ `ExecStopPost`?

Comment: You might want to clarify what you're trying to accomplish, for people who have no idea what systemd's ExecStartPre/ ExecStopPost do.

Comment: @TJLuoma oh sure, basically run some commands _before_ or _after_ the main daemon, usually for init or tear-down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality in `launchd` (as far as I am aware, and I consider myself pretty familiar with `launchd`).

The best site that I know of for `launchd` info is https://www.launchd.info which is maintained by the developer of [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) which is my favorite, and I would argue also the best, tool for managing `launchd` on the Mac, although I do have to admit that [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) is also excellent.

If I wanted to do something like that with `launchd` I would end up making a shell script of some kind to run the command before, then run the daemon, then run the commands after. Not nearly as satisfying, of course.